# How to generate google maps link for multiple source address?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

I would like to know how to add multiple source address as Google Maps allows through link,
if I want a source and a destination, this example link below works just fine:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=-12.2531892,-38.9538593&daddr=-12.2466969,-38.921826
```

But if I don't know how to add multiple addresses source, so the route stops at the first source address, then it goes from the first source to the second source, finally it goes to destination address

Is there a way to generate a link to multiple source addresses?

Comment: You can use 'waypoints'

Comment: You can use Google Maps URLs as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910653/5140781