# How to open a cyclic (non A-B) route in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

The goal is to generate a url similar to this:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bank+of+America+Financial+Center,+West+Dickson+Street,+Fayetteville,+AR/36.0665132,-94.1683564/@36.0666112,-94.1685074,20.5z/data=!4m24!4m23!1m20!1m1!1s0x89e60a1eeb4250dd:0xccaa89765c751072!2m2!1d-94.1683167!2d36.0663015!3m4!1m2!1d-94.1670086!2d36.06649!3s0x87c96edc06ed02d9:0xe92e6aa200c35b43!3m4!1m2!1d-94.1577513!2d36.0680627!3s0x87c96ed16b367e35:0xd874589e93cbbf83!3m4!1m2!1d-94.1685859!2d36.0672041!3s0x87c96edc39a53117:0x7b5afe32bea48704!1m0!3e0

Google maps generally finds shortest paths between distinct points. We have an algorithm that generates an array of lat long points in a poly line. In google maps you can manually drag portions of a route to view the desired path, poly line, instead of the shortest. The problem is generating a url given a poly line. as you can see in the above URL it has the destination points as well as some of the lat longs but there is extra information we can't find documentation on and have not been able to reverse engineer.

Does anyone know how google maps generates urls for poly lines of simple non destination lat longs

Comment: Use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) with waypoints similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910653/5140781

Comment: I don't want way points that are individual destinations I want one seamless route. When using waypoints it only shows you the distance to your next waypoint instead of the distance of the entire route as well as the next point of navigational interest. Basically we don't want the route to think you have arrived at a destination every time you make a turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [unofficial, undocumented, and unsupported older Google Maps URL scheme](https://hofmeister.it/google-maps-url-parameter/), which includes a `via` parameter that allows you to specify the indices (zero-based) of the waypoints that should not be [stopovers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints):

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=Bank+of+America,703+W+Dickson+Street,+Fayetteville,+AR+72701&daddr=36.066481,-94.167010+to:36.068063,-94.157744+to:36.067205,-94.168591+to:701+W+Dickson+St,+Fayetteville,+AR+72701&dirflg=d&via=1,2,3

Do note that this ***not*** supported. Google may change or even remove the old URL scheme, causing your link to potentially break in the future, in which case you'll have to use the [officially documented Google Maps URL scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-examples-using-waypoints):

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Bank+of+America,703+W+Dickson+St,+Fayetteville,+AR+72701&destination=701+W+Dickson+St,+Fayetteville,+AR+72701&travelmode=driving&waypoints=36.066481,-94.167010%7C36.068063,-94.157744%7C36.067205,-94.168591

You may also want to [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=195646&template=861509) in Google's Public Issue Tracker to allow for the official Maps URL scheme to allow non-stopover waypoints.