# Open map to show direction from current location through intent-Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent

I have many latitude longitude in my android app. I want to know how to open a chooser or Google map App through intent and show direction from current location to that latitude and longitude.Like i have lat=28.605989,lon=77.372970 and my current location is somewhere so when i click on button in my app these lat lon pass through intent and will show direction from my current location to these lat lon. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To navigate user to destination lat long, we can use something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=28.605989,77.372970"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Here . we are passing just destination lat long `daddr=28.605989,77.372970`, so by default, your current location will be source location.

To add extra information with your url .

```
String my_data= String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=20.5666,45.345(My Destination Place)");

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(my_data));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @GouravManuja sure thing. maek sure you have installed google map in your phone . otherwise you have to handle `ActivityNotFound` Exception

Comment: sir i m trying your code but my studio says not responding that's why its take so longer but i want to know one more thing...can i pass info window through intent on google map ???

Comment: like i want to show some information about location but i m using google map through intent so i want to know can i show my information on google map???

Comment: @GouravManuja . for information im updating my answer

Comment: sir you are great,done  current location to end points,but suppose i have lat lon of a doctor,i want to show the name of doctor the no of doctor and the time to meet him...so explain how can i show ???

Comment: sir i am passing data like this but where would show data which i passed on maps???

Comment: Sir String is not showing anywhere in map...where can i see that string which i pass in map ??

Comment: you can modify your string like this . 
`String my_data= String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=20.5666,45.345",20.5666,45.345, "Doctor Name \n 10 docs \n 12:30PM");`

Comment: Sir i cant see anywhere...firstly i want to know where can i see these all data on map....how can i see...i passed data hardcoded but it is not visible anywhere...where is it visible??

Comment: You have to encode your string `Uri.encode() `. please visit [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) link . see URI encoded query strings part .you will get clear idea .

Comment: sir i encode my string 
            Uri.encode("1st & Pike, Seattle")
like this...but i m not able to see data anywhere...
is it okay to unicode string ???
where would show my data ???

Comment: @GouravManuja updated my answer . pass with `lat,long(label)`

Comment: Sir where can i see my string on map ??

Comment: @GouravManuja on the destination address pin

Comment: sir i can't share the image of map...here is showing nothing...which string i passed

Comment: @TejasPandya Is there any official documentation of this URL which you added as String in Uri.parse?

Comment: @MustufaAnsari I would suggest you to please go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910653/6880611).

Answer (score 2):

You can send intent to Google Map android application by following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=22.458,34.34&daddr=75.124,35.448"));
startActivity(intent);
```

In the above URI `saddr` represents the source address i.e. your current location and `daddr` represents the coordinates of the destination location.

Comment: i think u define here your current location but i don't have current location i just have end points so what should i do for current location bcz i can be anywhere so this is not fix i want from my current location to my end points which i have,show direction

Comment: eventually, there is no such intent URI provided according to android documentation. you need to fetch current co-ordinates before redirecting to the google map.

Comment: you mean i should find out current location and pass with saddr  and end points pass with daddr ?
through intent in map i can't find my current location?

Comment: you can try the answer submitted by Tejas. if it doesn't work then you need to retrieve the current location first. try passing only the destination co-ordinates.

Comment: sir i m trying your code but my studio says not responding that's why its take so longer but i want to know one more thing...can i pass info window through intent on google map ??? 
like i want to show some information about location but i m using google map through intent so i want to know can i show my information on google map???